# A custom function in Vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'm quite new to Vim/Vi, and I need to write a custom function/macro.
Is it possible to define a command (ex. :mycommand) that would format the lines in the current file like so:

Initial lines:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2

This is line 3
This is line 4

This is line 5

This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
```

Result:

```
This is line 1\nThis is line 2
This is line 3\nThis is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6\nThis is line 7\nThis is line 8
```

How do I go about creating such a script? And where do I place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Marco

You can record a macro, to join two lines by `\n` separator, for example in your vimrc:

```
let @x='gJi\n^['
```

(the `^[` above, you press `ctrl-v Esc`)

Assume your cursor is on the first line, you can do `@x` in normal mode, then `)J@@` for the 2nd block, then job is done.

You can wrap those operations in function or create them as mapping.

#### Join plugin

I have written a `Join` script: https://github.com/sk1418/Join , it supports to join lines with separator and other features, in your case, you can execute command: `:J '\n'`, it will do what above macro `(@x)` does. You can put it in your function too, like:

```
function Foo()
   Join '\n'
   join!
   Join '\n'
endfunction
```

## Update for the Question modification:

The modification you made, turned the question into another one... However it could be solved, I listed two possibilities below, one is vim way, the other is with external awk tool, if you have awk available on your system.

#### with vim `:s` cmd

This command should do it for you:

```
%s/\n\n/∢/g|%s/\n\ze./\\n/g|%s/∢/\r/g
```

- the `∢` is done by pressing `ctrl-v u2222`, it is just for a special char, which not exists in your text, you can use other uni-code chars too.

#### with external awk

```
%!awk -v RS='\n\n' '{gsub(ORS, "\\n")}7'
```

This will do the transformation for you, however it leaves an extra `\n` at the end of the file, just remove it.

Comment: I'm sorry my initial example was unclear, I need the macro to process all the lines in a file. I've created such a macro in MS Word, but it beats me how to do it in Vim.

Comment: Thank you! The substitution command works great. But can I make a shortcut for it in vimrc? Or a function? I've just tried to add it inside a function but it won't do anything this way.

Comment: sure you can. @RayP. just put `nnoremap <F11> :%s/\n....../g<cr>` into your vimrc. and pressing `F11` will trigger the transformation.

Comment: If I put it in vimrc like that, when I press F11 I get these messages:
Pattern not found: \n\ze.
Trailing characters.

Comment: @RayP. have you tested with same example?

Comment: Yes, both with the same example and replacing the special character with a unique character combination, like "Ji82fhhh"

Comment: @RayP. I see, in your mapping, you should replace `|` by `<bar>` . that is `nnoremap <F11> :%s/\n.../g<bar>%s/../../g<bar>%s/./../g<cr>`